# how to see if a word starts with char g-z(python 3)

Tags: python-3.x

How do you see if a word starts with letters g-z using the .startswith() without doing a whole bunch of or's:
for example is it possible to do this:

```
if word.startswith(g-z):
```

without doing this:

```
if word.startswith(h) or word.startswith(i) or word.startswith(j) ect...:
```

BTW I'm not aloud to import things

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if re.match('[g-z]', word):
   ...
```

Or if you really, really don't want to use `re`:

```
if 'g' <= word[0] <= 'z':
   ...
```

Comment: does this work in python 3, cause it's telling me re is not defined?

Comment: Did you try importing it?

Comment: I'm not aloud to do that for this project.